# Calculate $\partial(|z|^2+1)$ and $\bar{\partial}((\bar{z}|z|^2+1) \cdot \sin(z))$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I don't understand this notation.

> Calculate $\partial(|z|^2+1)$ and $\bar{\partial}((\bar{z}|z|^2+1)\cdot \sin(z))$

They're asking me to find the derivatives with respect to $z$ and $\bar{z}$ resp.?

In that case, are my solutions correct?

> $a)$ $\partial(|z|^2+1)=\partial(\bar{z}z+1)=\bar{z}$
>
> $b)$ $\bar{\partial}((\bar{z}|z|^2+1)\cdot \sin(z))=\bar{\partial}((\bar{z}^2\cdot z+1)\cdot \sin(z))=2\bar{z}z\cdot \sin(z)$

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I also don't understand the notation, so you're not the only one! ;)

Comment: @PrasunBiswas and I can't ask to my professor before the exam because he has 4 days off...

Comment: Perhaps you can try reaching him by email?

Comment: I have seen this notation to denote what you suggest before.

Comment: @AlfredYerger And is my solution correct?

Comment: Yes, your solution is absolutely correct.  Algebra is a wonderful friend who allows you to make computations while not knowing (acording to your own admission) exactly what that computation means  :-)

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg I was like a kid aiming with a rifle to a mosquito. Thanks Georges!

Comment: You are welcome, dear Relure. Let me emphasize that it is quite ok to do calculations without "really" knowing what they mean: we all learned to compute $37\times 12$ without having heard about the Peano axioms... The calculations you asked about are part of a technique in analytic function thory called the Wirtinger calculus. You can read about it (after your exam!) in Remmert's book [Theory of complex functions](https://books.google.fr/books?id=CC0dQxtYb6kC&printsec=frontcover&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=true).

Comment: Beware that many threads about the Wirtinger calculus  on this site are complete fiddle-faddle, invoking functionsof $z$ alone that do not depend on $\bar z$, and such piffle. Keep to Remmert or to this interesting semi-historical [article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives).